# Solving PDE with Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have done a few of these now but I'm stuck at this one

$$\begin{array}{}
u_{xx}=u_{tt}+2u_t \\
u(0,t)= u(\pi,t)= 0 \\
u(x,0)=0, \, u_t(x,0)=\sin ^3x \\
\end{array}
$$
for $0<x< \pi$ and $t>0$.

So I rewrite $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, plug it in and separate the variables. That gives me

$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X}=\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}+2\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=- \lambda
$$ 
which leads me to these two ODEs
$$
T''(t) +2 T'(t)+ \lambda T(t) = 0 \\
X''(x)+\lambda X(x) = 0
$$
These I can solve but I am a little bit confused how to combine the Boundary- and Initial conditions for it. Should I just solve these and put them together and then check the conditons or can i do it simultaneously? What about $\lambda$, do I get different solutions depending on the sign? Can anyone show me how I should begin with this?

EDIT:

Ok so I took some advice from below and got to this:

For $\lambda≤0$ there is only the trivial solution (got that from the boundary conditions), so consider $\lambda>0$. We then write $\lambda=\omega^2$ and that would give me the solution

$$
X(x)=A\cos(\omega x)+ B\sin(\omega x)
$$
And from the boundry conditions I would end up with

$$
X(x)=B \sin(nx), \, for\, n=1,2,3,...
$$

Now what? What is $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, first pay attention to the variable whose boundary conditions are homogeneous. Here, the variable that you may consider first is $x$. Since

$$\begin{array}{}
u(0,t)=X(0)T(t)=0 & \to X(0)=0 \\
u(\pi,t)=X(\pi)T(t)=0 & \to X(\pi)=0 \\
\end{array}
$$

and hence you should start by first solving the following eigen-value problem

$$\begin{array}{}
X''+ \lambda X =0  \\
X(0)=0 \\
X(\pi)=0 \\
\end{array}
$$

The solution to this eigen-value problem will be

$$\begin{array}{}
X(x)=\sin(nx), & n=1,2,3,... \\
\lambda=n^2 \\
\end{array}
$$

and hence the differential equation for $T(t)$ will be

$$T''(t) + 2 T'(t) + n^2 T(t) = 0$$

and the solution to this ODE is

$$T(t)=A_n e^{-t} \cos(\sqrt{n^2-1}t) + B_n e^{-t} \sin(\sqrt{n^2-1}t)$$

and hence

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( A_n e^{-t} \cos(\sqrt{n^2-1}t) + B_n e^{-t} \sin(\sqrt{n^2-1}t) \right) \sin(nx)$$

and the derivative of $u(x,t)$ with respective to time will be

$$
u_t(x,t) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( A_n e^{-t} \left( -\cos(\sqrt{n^2-1}t)+ \sqrt{n^2-1} \sin(\sqrt{n^2-1}t) \right) \\ 
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad
 + B_n e^{-t} \left( -\sin(\sqrt{n^2-1}t)+ \sqrt{n^2-1} \cos(\sqrt{n^2-1}t) \right) \right) \sin(nx)
$$

and finally applying the intial conditions will lead you to

$$\begin{array}{}
u(x,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \sin(nx) = 0 \to &  A_n=0
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{}
u_t(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \sqrt{n^2-1} \sin(nx)
\end{array} = \sin^3(x)$$

and I just leave finding the coefficients $B_n$ for you. :)

Comment: OK I took some advice added that to my question above, maybe you can take a look? Im not really sure what you mean when you say that I should construct that series. I should point out that I'm just a few weeks into these  course, so everything about these orthogonal functions isn't THAT clear at the moment. I am however pretty comfortable with Fourier series and how to use them.

Comment: @Danny: See the updated answer. Also, you can choose $B$ as what as you like! The simplest case is $B=1$

Comment: I think that your method is a little bit too advanced for me, the book has some different approach at these problems. They solve $X(x)$ and then move over to $T(t)$ and uses Fourier series to solve that. I think we will arrive to your method with eigen-functions in a few weeks.

Comment: @Danny: OK! :) Think in the way you feel relaxed! :) Are you OK with your problem now or I should explain in some easy language for you! :)

Comment: I'm not really sure how to put $T(t)$ and $X(x)$ together tho. If i solve the characteristic equation for $T(t)$ and use that I get the solution 
$$
T(t)=Ae^{(-1+\sqrt{1-n^2})t}+Be^{(-1-\sqrt{1-n^2})t}
$$ 
and what to I do with this? Since it depends on $n$ i mean.

Comment: @Are you sure about your solution! It is not defined for $n \ge 2$!

Comment: Hmm. This solution would hold for $n=1$ and for $n>1$ I would have 
$$
T(t)=Ce^{-t}(cos(\sqrt{1-n^2}t)+sin(\sqrt{1-n^2}t))
$$
right? This just mess it up more haha.

Comment: OK, I will write the whole solution for you, in some proper time. I should go now. :)

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: @Danny: Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! At least I got some parts right, now I got a complete idea of what I should do, really great!

Comment: @Danny: You are welcome. :)